# Xcode 7, Swift 2.0 conversion: "duplicate symbol" and linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, linker-errors, swift2, xcode7

I've just updated my Xcode v6, Swift 1, iOS 7.1 app to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 using the converter and doing some manual changes to get rid of all the build errors concerning the swift files.
But I still get an `linker command failed with exit code 1`after I solved all issues...

I've tried all solutions I could find in the net including:

- delete the hosts settings in the build of the test-variables
- tried to clean all folders and builds including the derived data
- tried to set Bitcode to NO
- in the `toolbox-Bridging-Header.h` I've done `#import <receiptValidationHelper.h>` and not the .m file

nothing of the above solved the issue.

The link error shown after a few warnings are:

```
duplicate symbol _global_bundleIdentifier in:
/Users/soko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/toolbox-bpiaqlzxdtrbqwekzouzpbfnqxaa/Build/Intermediates/toolbox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/toolbox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/receiptValidationHelper.o
/Users/soko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/toolbox-bpiaqlzxdtrbqwekzouzpbfnqxaa/Build/Intermediates/toolbox.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/toolbox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwashTypeController.o
....
ld: 67 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code with the `global_bundleidentifier` is just in the `receiptValidationHelper.h` looking like this

```
const NSString *global_bundleVersion = @"1";
const NSString *global_bundleIdentifier = @"xxxx";
```

As mentioned above my app is Swift and I use this constant in the swift code as well. I imported the .h file in the `toolbox-Bridging-Header.h` using `#import <receiptValidationHelper.h>`

I've also tried to rename `const NSString *global_bundleIdentifier = @"xxx";` which leads to the same error with the new name.

EDIT:
If I remove all the usages of `global_bundleIdentifier`in my Swift code the error is gone! It seems something is new in Swift 2.0 concerning the use of variables of Objective-C code. Does anybody now exactly what I have to change?

Comment: Can you post some code please?  Specifically, the code with `global_bundleIdentifier`.

Comment: done. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an C problem, not a Swift one.  Your problem is that global variables are global -- they can be accessed by the entire program.  Declaring these globals in a header causes them to be defined in every file that `#import`s the header, confusing the linker since there are 67 definitions of the same constants.

You need to move the definitions to `receiptValidationHelper.m` so there's just one globally-accessible copy of each constant.

However, if you just move the constants to the .m, the compiler will complain anywhere you try to use them since it can't find them, so add these lines to `receiptValidationHelper.h`:

```
extern const NSString *global_bundleVersion;
extern const NSString *global_bundleIdentifier;
```

The `extern` directives tell  the compiler, "hey, these constants are defined somewhere else."  The compiler then acts like they exists and let's the linker deal with it.

Comment: great. that worked. thanks heaps. One question remains though: Why is this an issue now? The exact same code was fine in Xcode 6...